# What will be the behavior of $R(t)$ if $R(0)=\alpha / \beta$ in Vasicek model

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

Can someone please help explain what the behavior of $R(t) = \alpha / \beta$ would be if

$dR(t)=(\alpha-\beta R(t))dt +\sigma dW(t)$

I already know the expression for R(t) and I know the mean and variance. I just dont understand what would happen to $R(t)$ if $R(0)=\alpha / \beta$

Comment: Do you mean ? $$\lim_{t \to T}R(t) \to \frac{\alpha}{\beta}$$